# Android + saxParser endElement finished looping?

Tags: android, saxparser

Using saxParser, how can I tell when the endElement is complete?  Unforunately I have a rather large XML file and need to store all my data into an ArrayList before passing it to the InsertHelper utility.  How do I test if the saxParser has completed its looping?

```
/**
 * Called when tag opening ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> -- <name> )
 */
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    currentElement = true;

    if (localName.equals("StoreDetails")) {
        //Log.i("TAG", "Store Details");
        newKOPStoreVersion = attributes.getValue("stores_version");
        //if (!dBHelper.getStoreXMLVersion().equals(newKOPStoreVersion)) { BUT BACK
        Log.i("TAG", "Store Details Changed");
        isStoreDetailsVersionChanged = true;
        //dBHelper.deleteStoreDetail();
        //currentValue = "";
        //buffer = new StringBuffer();
        dBHelper.setStoreXMLVersion(newKOPStoreVersion);
        /*}
        else BUT PACK
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "no change for KOP store version");
            throw new KOPSAXTerminatorException();
        }*/
    }

}

/**
 * Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> -- </name> )
 */
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;     

    //if (isStoreDetailsVersionChanged == true) { PUT BACK
    if (localName.equals("StoreID")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setStoreId(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("StoreName")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setStoreName(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("StoreDescription")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setStoreDescription(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("Location")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setLocation(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("Phonenumber")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setPhoneNumber(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("VisualmapID")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setVisualMapId(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("x")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setCartX(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("y")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setCartY(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("ClosestParkingLot")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setClosestParkingLot(buffer.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("RelatedCategory")) {
        buffer.toString().trim();
        storeDetails.setRelatedCategory(buffer.toString());
        //add buffer to arraylist - then loop array do the ih dance
        dataList.add(storeDetails);
//this is my arraylist and I'm attempting to loop over it outside of this class, but it seems to only contain the last value of the xml, not all the values.

    }

    buffer = new StringBuffer();

    //}
    if (localName.equals("StoreDetails")) {
        //Log.i("TAG","End StoreDetails");
        isStoreDetailsVersionChanged = false;
        //throw new KOPSAXTerminatorException();
    }
}

/**
 * Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> -- to get
 * AndroidPeople Character )
 */
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (currentElement) {
        buffer.append(ch, start, length);
        currentElement = false;
    }
}
```

I can send you the complete code if you're willing to look at it.

Comment: theres an enddocument method that you can override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End document gets called when the SAX parser is finished. All you have to do is override the method in your handler (the same class that has the element methods.

```
 @Override
 public void endDocument() throws SAXException {

 }
```